# Get User objects from foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django Rest Framework. I have two models as shown below:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

What I'd like to have an API that will return all the followers the user has. However, I don't want it to be returned in the `Following` model format, I'd like for the followers to be returned as users in this format:

```
[
 {
     "username": Bob,
     "email": example@example.com
 },
 {
     "username": Charlie,
     "email": example@example.com
 }
]
```

Right now, I have something like this:

```
class FollowingAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Following.objects.filter(target=3)

class FollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Following
        fields = ('follower', 'target')
```

This only shows the `follower` and `target` I don't want this. I want the actual data from `User` Also, I put `target=3` as a placeholder just to test.

Comment: Is that supposed to be your complete output? In which case it seems like you should be using a serializer on the User model, not on Following; you can restrict the users to those following the target in your `get_queryset` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hmm, I'm getting an error when I change the serializer to be on the User model. It says that it has no attribute called `username`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use a serializer for the `User` not `following`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_following = serializer.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_following')
```

also, change your queryset in view as below:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404

class FollowingAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowingSerializer

    ### so add this method to get the requested user based on the username in the url
    def get_requested_user(self):
        ##get the user based on the user name in url
        filter_kwargs = {'username': self.kwargs['username']} 
        obj = get_object_or_404(User.objects.all(), **filter_kwargs)
        return obj

    def get_queryset(self):
         requested_user = self.get_requested_user()
         return User.objects.filter(targets__target=requested_user)\
             .annotate(is_following=models.Count('followers', filter=models.Q(followers__follower=requested_user), distinct=True))
```

if you are using Django<2.0, your `get_queryset` should be like:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
         requested_user = self.get_requested_user()
         return User.objects.filter(targets__target=requested_user)\
             .annotate(is_following=models.Count(models.Case(models.When(models.Q(followers__follower=requested_user), 1))))
```

because you want to return a list of users, not Following instances. use following only to filter( `targets__` in the filter above) the users that their `target` in `Following` is the currently authenticated user(at least in one of its targets).

**updated**

also, change your url to something like this:

```
path('/api/followers/<username>/', FollowingAPIView.as_view(), name='get_user_followers')
```

Comment: This works great! Is there a way I can add an extra field as the output JSON response? Like for example, I want to know whether or not the target user follows that follower. So the output could be something like `[{ "username": Bob, "email": e@example.com, is_following: 1 }]` 1 indicates that the target does follow the user and 0 indicating that the target does not

Comment: yeah, I think you can use annotate, I will update my answer.

Comment: Hmm, for `models` it's saying it is an unresolved reference

Comment: import it `from django.db import models`

Comment: This works like a charm! And last question if you could answer it, I'd like to filter not based on the logged in user, but based on what is in the url. For example, `/api/followers/bob` will return all bob's followers `/api/followers/charlie` will return all of charlie's followers

Comment: Hmm, it's weird I'm I did everything you said but I keep on getting a 404 error even though the user does exist...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178809/discussion-between-changak-and-user2896120).

Comment: I actually noticed something that isn't right. The annotation gets all the targets for who the user follows and doesn't check if the user follows that specific target.

Comment: the annotation for each instance of the queryset counts the number of Following instances if the follower is the `get_requested_user`

Comment: Because the field is_follower becomes more than 1 sometimes and should only be 1 or 0 if the user follows that user or not

Comment: oh so sorry, my bad, I just reviewed my answer, and you are right  the filtering part is wrong. just updated it.

Comment: Hmm, I just got home and I tried it again and it's still not working correctly...

Comment: I guess you are using Django < 2.0, I updated my answer for that case.